# RxJs Wait for Promise to Resolve Before Continuing to Read Emitted Values

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

For every value emitted I want to do some asynchronous processing.

My goal is to **wait** before accepting the next value until `myPromise` has been resolved.

```js
events.pipe(awaitPromise(async event => await myPromise(event))).subscribe();
```

Notes:

- I don't know how long the promise will take to execute
- Values emitted during the "pause" must not be discarded

---

I am not quite sure if this is even possible with RxJs. Maybe I need to implement some other kind of "queuing" system? But it would be really convenient for me to do it with RxJs!

Comment: Do you mean waiting for `myPromise` to be resolved before it is subscribed?

Comment: @wentjun No, every time a new `event` is emitted I want to "pause", wait for `myPromise` to resolve and then continue processing incoming `events`. And repeat "forever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concatMap`, you won't lose any events, they all queue up until promise resolved.

```
events.pipe(concatMap(event=>from(promiseFn(event)))
```